# How to close a pdf opened with fitz if I've replaced its variable name?

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

This is a simple issue. I use jupyter notebook for python and usually deal with pdfs using pymupdf.

I usually define `pdf = fitz.open('dir/to/file.pdf')` but somethimes I forget to close the file before i redefine `pdf = fitz.open('dir/to/other_file.pdf')`

Sometimes I need to (for example) move or delete `file.pdf` (the original file) but I can't because python is using it.

Not being an expert, I don't know how to close this file when I have redefined the variable `pdf`, as obviously `pdf.close()` would close 'other_file.pdf' and I end up reeinitializing my .ipynb file, which feels dumb.

How can I access an object which variable name has been redefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writting this issue made me think about `globals()`

Browsing throughout its keys I found that the objects which variables have been reused are stored with dummy names (don't know the term used for them). I found the object I was looking for and I was able to 'close' it.

If there's a better - more elegant solution, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `Document.save("newname.pdf")` then that new file, `newname.pdf` will be immediately available for other processes - it is not blocked by the process you are currently executing.

The original file however, `oldname.pdf`, from which you have created your `Document` object remains owned by your current process.
It will be freed if you do a `Document.close()`.

But there is a way to work with the `oldname.pdf` under PyMuPDF without blocking it. It actually entails making a memory-resident copy:

```py
import pathlib
import fitz

pdfbytes = pathlib.Path("oldname.pdf").read_bytes()
# from here on, file oldname.pdf is fully available
doc = fitz.open("pdf", pdfbytes)
# doc can be saved under any name, even the original one.
```

Comment: Well that indeed solves the issue with the opened file, but I was more interested in the "access an object which variable name has been redefined" part. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see your problem: if you do `a = some_object` and then `b = a`, then `b`is just another label pointing to the exact same object: if `some_object` is changed then this is also reflected in `b`.